# Why can't gdal open my VRT?

Tags: gdal, vrt

I am trying to reproject and retile BMNG data. So far I have processing my images into geotifs. I can view them together in QGIS and everything looks good:

[image]

I then created a vrt file. The vrt file lives in the same folder as the tifs. When I attempt to open the vrt in QGIS or run gdalwarp on it, I get the following error: 
`ERROR 4: \1_3.tif: No such file or directory`

The lines in the vrt that reference the offending tif look like this:

`<SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">\1_3.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="512" RasterYSize="512" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="512" BlockYSize="5" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="512" ySize="512" />
      <DstRect xOff="1536" yOff="1536" xSize="512" ySize="512" />
</SimpleSource>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tifs are actually named "1_3.tif", not "\1_3.tif" then you need to remove the backslash.

```
<SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">1_3.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="512" RasterYSize="512" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="512" BlockYSize="5" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="512" ySize="512" />
      <DstRect xOff="1536" yOff="1536" xSize="512" ySize="512" />
</SimpleSource>
```

Comment: Thank you! It turns out I was running gdalbuildvrt with <output_path>\*.tif and I had an extra backslash.